# Trigger jQuery datetimepicker on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datetimepicker

I am using this datetimepicker: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

I have a form where users can dynamically add more fields.  I haven't been able to find a way to get the datetimepicker to show on the dynamically-added fields.

Here is a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/coxafodace/1/edit?html,js,output

I have tried using live() and onclick() and a whole bunch of other things, but the datetimepicker always appears on the last non-dynamic form field, never on the newly-created form field.

So what can I do to trigger the datatimepicker on the dynamic fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are cloning the last repeated item so it has the same events, same everything. A better way to do it is to make a template with:

```
<script type="text/template" id="date-time-template">
    //repeated html goes in here
</script>
```

And then in your javascript append a new instance and initialize the datepicker on the NEW html.

```
var repeatingTemplate = $('#date-time-template').html();

jQuery('.repeat').click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();

    //Creates a NEW jquery object of the same html
    var $repeating = $(repeatingTemplate);
    var lastRepeatingGroup = jQuery('.repeating').last();

    //places the new line after the last one
    lastRepeatingGroup.after($repeating);

    //binds the datetime events to the newly added line
    $repeating.find('.starttime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        // mask: true,
        format:'H:i',
        step: 15,
    });

    $repeating.find('.endtime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        // mask: true,
        format:'H:i',
        step: 15,
    });
});
```

[Here is an updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qasodeluko/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm still testing this on my site... I see that it works in the jsbin, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on my site.  This is on a WordPress site, and WordPress doesn't like jQuery's "$".  I think I can get it working though.....

Comment: It works in jsbin, but still having trouble getting it to work on my site.  I tried console.log(repeatingTemplate) and it is undefined.  Is there another way to identify the section that needs to repeat?

Comment: Oh!  Nevermind!  The problem was with a PHP conditional tag that was stopping the template from rendering.  :P  All functional now!  Thank you!